# Compare huge table(100 million rows) data between Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a process which populates an Oracle table which has over 100 million rows.
The table structure is as follows

```
**ORACLE_TABLE**
id|contractdatetime|Attr3|Attr4|Attr5
```

The combination of `(id,contractdatetime)` is unique in this table, which gets populated using an external process.

The total `distinct id` is approx 30000 only.
For every id there is a unique contractdatetime. The id isn't unique, but the combination of `(id,contractdatetime)` is

Now another process populates an identical table in SQL Server

```
**SQLSERVER_TABLE**
id|contractdatetime|Attr3|Attr4|Attr5
```

I am thinking about the best way to check if the data is both tables is identical.
I thought if I can get a hashed version by `contractid` and somehow aggregate all the other attributes in Oracle. And if I can do the same in SQL Server, I would be able to compare this in Excel itself (30000) rows.

I have searched StackOverflow and couldn't get an identical function for MD5_XOR or anything which can help achieve this as per the link below.
http://www.db-nemec.com/MD5/CompareTablesUsingMD5Hash.html

The other options of using a linked server etc would take lot more difficulty in getting approvals for doing this.

Is there a good way to go about with this?

Comment: Hashing is not foolproof because it can easily yield collisions. Why do you need two copies of the same 100 million row table? Can't they both reference the same copy somehow?

Comment: @AaronBertrand They are both loaded using two separate process( with identical logic). The task is to see at high level if the data matches. For example we do check out the recrod counts as a first level, and if it matches, then opt for comparison using hashing/ or some other means

Comment: But why are you loading two copies at all? And why do you think hashing 3 values into one, on both sides, will be faster than just comparing all three on both sides?

Comment: The new process is meant to stave off the first process, if the data matches. The oracle process is the legacy one and the new process would be used by the consumers going forward

Comment: If you want to be sure the new process produces identical results, I would compare the columns independently rather than spend time trying to find some reliable hashing approach. It's not going to pay off even if you could trust it, IMHO.

Comment: Thats true, i am seeking options or better ideas on how to compare, reasonably

Comment: Well, "reasonably" is a trade-off only you can decide. You can trade speed for accuracy to some degree, but if you want full confidence, don't waste time on shortcuts (especially copying and pasting 100 million hash values, twice, to Excel - and expecting it not to barf on you). Get the approval to create your linked server, temporarily, and compare directly.

Comment: Just to mention, i wouldnt need to get 100 million hashes, 30000 hashs is what i would need to compare

Comment: Both products have features to export data to flat files, yes? Can you experiment with exporting _just one row_ from each source to a file so that the resulting files are identical? If so, you could export the 30K rows from each source to two files, and run any number of diff programs against them. If you only care about 30,000 rows, I think this is doable (but you should probably take the "100 million rows" variable out of the question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227699/discussion-between-george-joseph-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: if both oracle and sql server tables are relative statics, I would spool / save files in csv format, then copy both csv files to a unix hosts to do sdiff both files. this is just one of idea to get a fast comparsion for both dataset.

Comment: the above mothod will works if both datasets are sorting same way when spool  or saving as csv

Comment: thanks, I am hoping somewhere in the lines of comparing an aggregated version of the 100 million rows by getting an aggregation of hashes by id, which there are only around 30 k for comparison

Comment: I wonder if you could optimize this to match the data hashes for just, say, the first 10,000 and last 10,000 rows. If both the first and last sets match, and the row counts match, it should be reasonable to assume the middle matches as well.

Comment: comparing 30K records was easy between two systems and have to say we saved a lot of time by the solution mentioned below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fast, high-level comparison between an Oracle and a SQL Server table you can use aggregations of the functions `STANDARD_HASH` and `HASH_BYTES`.

### Oracle Code

```
--Create a simple table.
create table table1
(
    id number,
    contractdatetime date,
    Attr3 varchar2(100),
    Attr4 varchar2(100),
    Attr5 varchar2(100)
);

--Insert 4 rows, the first three will be identical between databases,
--the last row will be different.
insert into table1 values (1, date '2000-01-01', 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into table1 values (2, date '2000-01-01', 'b', 'b', 'b');
insert into table1 values (2, date '2000-01-02', null, null, null);
insert into table1 values (3, date '2000-01-02', 'Oracle', 'Oracle', 'Oracle');
commit;

select
    id,
    --Format the number
    trim(to_number(
        --Sum per group.
        sum(
            --Convert to a number.
            to_number(
                --Get the first 14 bytes. This seems to be the maximum that SQL Server can handle
                --before it runs into math errors.
                substr(
                    --Hash the value.
                    standard_hash(
                        --Concatenate the values using (hopefully) unique strings to separate the
                        --columns and represent NULLs (because the hashing functions treat nulls differently.)
                        nvl(to_char(contractdatetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'null') || 
                        '-1-' || nvl(attr3, 'null') || '-2-' || nvl(attr3, 'null') || '-3-' || nvl(attr3, 'null')
                        , 'MD5')
                    , 1, 14)
                , 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
        , '99999999999999999999')) hash
from table1
group by id
order by 1;
```

### SQL Server Code

```
create table table1
(
    id numeric,
    contractdatetime datetime,
    Attr3 varchar(100),
    Attr4 varchar(100),
    Attr5 varchar(100)
);

insert into table1 values (1, cast('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime), 'a', 'a', 'a');
insert into table1 values (2, cast('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime), 'b', 'b', 'b');
insert into table1 values (2, cast('2000-01-02 00:00:00.000' as datetime), null, null, null);
insert into table1 values (3, cast('2000-01-02 00:00:00.000' as datetime), 'SQL Server', 'SQL Server', 'SQL Server');
commit;

select
    id,
    sum(
        convert(bigint, convert(varbinary, 
            substring(
                hashbytes('MD5',
                    isnull(convert(varchar(19), contractdatetime, 20), 'null') +
                    '-1-' + isnull(attr3, 'null') + '-2-' + isnull(attr3, 'null') + '-3-' + isnull(attr3, 'null'))
                , 1, 7)
            , 1))) hash
from table1
group by id
order by 1;
```

### Results

As expected, the hashes for the first two groups are identical, and the hash for the third group is different.

```
Oracle:

ID  HASH
1   50696302970576522
2   69171702324546493
3   50787287321473273

SQL Server

ID  HASH
1   50696302970576522
2   69171702324546493
3   7440319042693061
```

Here is an [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d161f043f1764a70e0dec2cfd0ad705) and a [SQL Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3584ae626970fba823abb9a116876bed).

### Problems

1. I assume this solution will only work if the databases use similar characters sets, or perhaps only use the first 127 ASCII characters that are often encoded the same in different character sets.
2. There is a (perhaps unreasonably) high chance of hash collisions. MD5 hashes aren't good enough for preventing cryptographic attacks, but they're good enough for comparing sets of data. The problem is that I had to use substrings to get the math to work for SQL Server. This is probably my fault for not understanding SQL Server well enough - BIGINTS should support roughly 19 digits of precision but my math only worked up to 14 digits. I probably have a conversion bug somewhere. You may need to play with the "14" and "7" numbers if you get too many collisions or overflow problems. (14 for Oracle, which counts based on the displayed hex characters. 7 for SQL Server, which counts based on the number of characters that can be represented by each hex characters, which is 0.5.)

Comment: This is very helpful, have a question on why 7 characters are substring in SQL Server while in Oracle its 14

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph I added an explanation about how Oracle counts based on displayed hex characters, and SQL Server counts based on the number of characters that can be represented by the the hex characters.