# Is it possible to compare databases from two different types of SQL

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to compare data from an Oracle DB and an Azure SQL DB. The data should be the same in each but I want to find out is there a way to check and confirm this?

I'm thinking maybe a Java application that could check and compare the same row of each application, or check totals/counts. Or is there a more straight forward way? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You need code it in Java for any reason? Because currently exist many tools and apps for this, I just look a bit on google and I found some tools for this. So idk if this required for a specific app or work

Comment: You might be able to compare each table with queries that produce hashes. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876015/409172) for queries that work for both Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give us more info about the story of the database.

Have you created an Azure SQL Database from an Oracle DB or the other way around?

My approach would be:

1. Use  [SSMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-ver16) to translate the Oracle database to a SQL Server database.
2. Now use any compare database you find online (there are many) and compare the two.

If you tell me more about the story of the database I can understand better.